# Is there an href attribute to add a contact, like “mailto:” or “tel:”?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a contact to the user smartphone (like when someone send you a contact via WhatsApp) on a website.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

There is no standard for adding a contact.

Also, Whatsapp doesn't offer a way to add a contact via an HTML request.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with HTML5:

```
 <p> Book now, call <a href ="tel:01234567890"> 01234 567 890</a></p>
```

For more refer [here](https://paulund.co.uk/add-telephone-number-links-with-html5).

Some suggestions are given [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-create-an-HTML-link-to-add-a-contact-to-the-smartphone-as-MECARD-QR-protocol-does).

Comment: This doesn't add a contact

Comment: If
`<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Hola Mundo" id="send_message">Enviar mensaje</a>`
asks you to open WhatsApp, how can I open the contacts list?